# PHP remove domain name from a string

Tags: php, string

I need to remove the domain name from the end of a string. I have tried the following code:

```
    $domainNAME="example.com";
    $result="_xmpp-client._tcp.example.com..example.com"
    $string = $result;
    $string = str_replace(".".$domainNAME, " ", $string);
```

Here the result is "**_xmpp-client._tcp.**". But the result should be "**_xmpp-client._tcp.example.com.**".

I need to remove the domain name only from the end of string, if domain name exists anywhere in the string it should not be removed.How can I change the code for that?

Any help should be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preg_replace and specify the end of string marker `$`:

```
$string = preg_replace("/" . $domainNAME . "$/", " ", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for fancy preg nor substr.. just use [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function :)

will remove from both ends

```
echo trim($string,$domainNAME);
```

will remove domainName from end of string

```
echo rtrim($string,$domainNAME);
```

will remove domainName from beging of string

```
echo ltrim($string,$domainNAME);
```

**Example**

```
echo rtrim('demo.test.example.com',"example.com");
//@return demo.test
```

**2nd method**

if not.. then use the preg match :).

```
$new_str = preg_replace("/{$domainNAME}$/", '', $str);
```

this will replace $domainNAME from $str ONLY if its at end of $str ($ sign after the var means AT end of string.

Comment: hmmm `echo rtrim($string,$domainNAME);` returns `_xmpp-client._t` here.

Comment: updated :).. sorry for that confusion

Comment: lol, that's my answer now :P

Comment: haha :D didnt see that :D Good job you should be accepted :D !

Answer (score 1):

```
$domainNAME="example.com";
$result="_xmpp-client._tcp.example.com..example.com";
$string = $result;
$string = substr($result,0, strrpos($result, $domainNAME)-1);   
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are truly wanting to have the output as `_xmpp-client._tcp.example.com.` with the dot at the end use

```
preg_replace("/\." . $domainNAME . "$/", " ", $string);
```

and you can add ? if you want it to be optional

```
preg_replace("/\.?" . $domainNAME . "$/", " ", $string);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/FLIil9)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $domainNAME="example.com";
            $length = strlen(".".$domainNAME);
            $result="_xmpp-client._tcp.example.com..example.com";
            $string = substr($result, 0, $length*(-1));
```

Try that. I wish it could help you

Comment: too much for a simple task.. preg_replace("/{$domainNAME}$/", '', $str); shall do in that case !

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_ireplace('example.com.example.com', 'example.com', $string);`